# Как в цикле for пропустить несколько итераций

Tags: python-3.x

Используя цикл for итерируясь по списку нужно пропустить подряд несколько элементов, а затем снова продолжить нормальную работу цикла.
Заранее неизвестно какие элементы списка нужно пропустить, это определяется по ходу выполнения цикла.

Comment: Заранее не известно в каком участке тела цикла нужно будет пропускать? Или все таки не известно количество пропускаемых элементов?  Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в тело вопроса, кнопка "править".

Comment: заранее неизвестно какие элементы списка нужно пропустить(за раз нужно пропустить 16 элементов списка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор `continue`:

Если речь про неизвестное количество пропускаемых элементов, то вот, например:

```
   skip = x
    for i in range():
        if i >= skip and i <= skip:
            continue
```

А если не известно в каком участке кода - хз.

Comment: Я конечно в пайтоне ни силён.. но такая конструкция пропустит ведь только итерацию с номером i=skip? Одновременное выполнение обоих условий? Автору ведь нужно пропустить всё что между skip и skip+16?

Comment: Да конечно, Вы правы ) Писал на вскидку.

Comment: информации из данного ответа достаточно что бы решить поставленную задачу